# How do you keep disc tray from opening once you are done with burning disc on windows 10

Tags: windows-10, dvd-burning, cd-burning

Is there any way to keep the disc tray from opening when I burn the disc using default windows 10 disc burner?

I need to run some process to the disc that just got burnt and it is inconvenient that the disc tray opens after successfully burning disc. I have to manually close the disc tray again before proceeding.

[image: burning disc successfully]

Comment: It is not a direct answer to your question, but if your problem is moving to the PC to physically close the drive (or the eject button is not working) there is this solution https://superuser.com/a/526548/939885 using PowerShell.

Comment: @user10191234 I have seen that post for sure. I asked this question because, while it does partially solve my problem, I was hoping that if disc ejection did not occur from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Windows Media Player to burn the disc, there is an option for "Eject disc after burning". Unchecking this option should keep the tray closed after the burn is complete.

In the version that is on my copy of Windows 10 (Windows Media Player 12.0.17763.1637), the option is under a little dropdown menu called Burn Options at the upper right corner of the Burn section of the interface.

[image: Windows Media Player eject option]

Comment: Nice! I did not know WMP can burn discs too. I will definitely use this from my next burning. So I am guessing there are no way of doing this on File Explorer burning.

Comment: When I right-click on a DVD drive in File Explorer, and go to Properties, I see a Recording tab with a option for "Automatically eject the disc after a Mastered burn". I'm not sure if that appears for all disc types and format, but it might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Interesting... I do not see that tab on the Drive properties nor Properties within Hardware Tab. May be because I do not have a disc inserted? I would have to try next time I am at the office.